# How can you run a custom function right before dbt run in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, dbt

I have an Airflow DAG with the following structure:

`task_visits_dedup >> task_dbt_run >> task_dbt_test`

`with visits_dag:`

```
task_visits_dedup = visits_dedup() # This function runs some SQL in Snowflake to deduplicate data

task_dbt_run = DbtRunOperator(
    task_id="dbt_run", 
    executor_config=executor_config,
    models="tag:ahoy",
    exclude="tag:staging",
    pool="dbt",
    retries=0
)

task_dbt_test = DbtTestOperator(
    task_id="dbt_test",
    executor_config=executor_config,
    models="tag:ahoy",
    exclude="tag:staging",
    retries=0,  # Failing tests would fail the task, and we don't want Airflow to try again
)`
```

The issue (I think) I'm facing is that when other (full refresh) DBT dags are running on Airflow, there will be a long time gap between task_visits_dedup and dbt_run execution, which allows for duplicated data to slip back in and the dbt_test to fail.

**Question**: How do you run `task_visits_dedup` *right before* (without a schedule delay) the dbt_run operation?

- dbt-core==0.20.0rc2
- airflow-dbt==0.4.0
- apache/airflow:2.0.2-python3.8

Thank you.

Comment: could you explain why do you need to run `task_visits_dedup` before `task_dbt_run`? looks like you don't need to wait `task_visits_dedup` completion.

Comment: Thank you, Danila. task_visits_dedup is needed to deduplicate data merged from multiple sources (fivetran + kafka). Downstream models (in dbt_run) require visits to be unique.

Comment: ok. But could you explain the problem in more detail? Perhaps the problem is in the slow `task_visits_dedup`?